# How to set form to $dirty by changing model pragmatically?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

If you look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/fvf1a3Q2fRErzdORbh76?p=preview) plunk, you see that if I change the model by using some function, the form doesn't get informed about it and it doesn't become dirty, how can I achieve this behavior?

```
 $scope.obj = {};

  $scope.setName = function() {
    $scope.name = "set name !";
  }

  <form name="form">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    </form>

    <button type="button" ng-click="setName()">
      setName
    </button>

    <br />
    {{form.$dirty}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design. The form becomes dirty is the user uses its control, not if the code modifies its underlying model.

But you can make the form (or a field of the form) dirty by using the form controller published in the scope by the form directive. In your case, since the form name is `form`, and assuming your input has a name:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" />

$scope.form.name.$setDirty()
```

Comment: you are right, but what if is use `ng-form` and `ng-repeat` , as you know accessing inner form in controller is not possible as far as I know. If I use interpolation for input names, doing so will become very dirty in my opinion, imagine 40 input types only 3 of them are empty and my validation messages are shown only when an input field become dirty.

Comment: Ask another question, with your real use-case.

Comment: @JG Nizet I asked a question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315388/setting-pre-populated-form-inputs-to-dirty-or-touched

Answer (score 0):

have you tried somehting like:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = "";
  $scope.obj = {};

  $scope.setName = function() {
    $scope.name = "set name !";
  }
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- By setting the version to snapshot (available for all modules), you can test with the latest master version -->
    <!--<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <form name="form">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" required />
    </form>

    <button type="button" ng-click="setName()">
      setName
    </button>

    <br />
    {{form.$dirty}}
    <br />
    {{form.$touched}}
    <br>
    {{form.$invalid}}

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add name attribute to your input element, here is the update [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0bml6qr7prdYjLS0eFDS?p=preview) of yours

```js
Using $scope.formName.filedName.$setDirty();
```

Comment: I think you snippet is broken. I don't see anything

Comment: sorry saved now